# Отключение разделителя в SplitPane (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

По ходу создания программы в JavaFX для красоты решил запретить изменять расположение разделителя (Divider). Вот моя попытка:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    sp.lookupAll(".split-pane-divider").stream().forEach(
            div -> div.setMouseTransparent(true));
}
```

, однако данный код никак не влияет разделитель.

Попытка выставить галку на Mouse Transparent в Scene Builder хоть и помогает, но также не дает выполнять действия внутри самого SplitPane. Прошу исправить мой код или написать иной способ решения данной проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В описании есть фраза :

> "Dividers moving to the left/top will stop when the node's min size is
>   reached."

Попробуйте зафиксировать его установив минимальные размеры внутренностей. В sceneBuilder при просмотре это сработало.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!